# Mysql date difference between current date and date stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, date

I have a task to fetch a list of employees from a table having experience greater than or equal to 2 years. I have the `'joined_date'`field in table `employee`.Am using cakephp framework.Can you suggest me the way for fetching the details.Thanks in advance.

Comment: See `datediff` in the [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). It will compute the difference between dates.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to connect to the database using one of various methods. Then use SQL to fetch the records.

Assuming the field **joined_date** is a timestamp and is in a table called **employee**...

Here is an example using odbc_connect...

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database
    $conn = odbc_connect($server ,$username ,$password );

    // Define the query
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM employee
        WHERE joined_date >= now() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR
    ";

    // Execute the query and assign the results to a resource
    $res = odbc_exec($conn,trim($query));

    // Loop through the results 
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) 
    {
        print_r($row);
    }

    // Close the connection
    odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

[PHP odbc_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)

[MySQL Date & Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)